# How to remove padding bottom in flutter

Tags: flutter

I've tried a few things to remove this padding-bottom but it seems doesn't work for me

here is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Test app'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  'images/mosque.svg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 950,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
     );
  }
```

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qs25.png)

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299946/14343554) can help you

Comment: Can you check if the picture is not having that white bar just to be clear?

Comment: I just fixed this by export only vector part from figma and it fixed @Chirag Bargoojar